# How to handle knowledgebase data storage-Angular

Tags: json, angular, postgresql

So I'm building a knowledge base which may contain 50-100 articles in an html page and might increase in the future ,
Currently I'm storing them as local JSON files in the assets folder and reading form those files and displaying them .My question is is there a more efficient way to store this in a db like mysql/postgres or any possible solution that will make this more scalable and reusable.

The reason for asking for an efficient way to store it in a DB is incase if an article is outdated then I can update the JSON stored in the DB and the changes take effect without much hassle(instead digging around in the local folder for those files).

currently what I'm doing in angular

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 templateUrl: './my-component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./my-component.css']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
 ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('/assets/data.json').subscribe().then(data => console.log(data));
 }
}
```

I'm new to this topic so any help or advice will be helpful .Thanks in advance

Comment: You kind of answered your own question by yourself. Having the data stored in a DB is usually much more beneficial than having it in a JSON file stored publicly. As you said, the data might change in the future and a database is a much more easier way to manage it, especially if relationships start to grow within it.

All you need now is an endpoint within your backend that you can query for the data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ,so these articles might be several paragraphs or less than  that depends on the data ,would storing/retrieving it in the DB cause any performance issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would usually bump into performance issues if you are executing search queries on the text columns, those force the DB to perform full table scans which cause a hit to the performance.

If at some point you decide that you need to search the article text, you might want to look into advanced indexing techniques or you might find it more convenient to use a full-text search engine like https://www.elastic.co/

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks again